# How to commend addition value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and this table have three column
like this

```
--------------
|Name|ID |Num|
--------------
|A   |001|1  |
|A   |001|2  |
|A   |001|3  |
--------------
```

I want show NAME ID and total of Num
like the anwser

```
NAME ID  NumTOTAL
A    001 6
```

Comment: Wouldn't the total be `6` rather than `5`, or are we missing something?

Comment: just my key in wrong Thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `SUM()`:

```
SELECT Name, ID, SUM(Num) AS NumTOTAL
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name, ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy after using sum() function of sql

```
select name,id sum(num) as [Total Num] from tableName Group by name,id
```

Comment: Note that square brackets for delimited identifiers is product specific, ANSI SQL has double quotes, e.g. `"Total Num"`. (MS SQL Server accepts that too.)